# How do I add body onload using PrimeFaces Mobile?

Tags: mobile, jsf-2, primefaces

I simply want to output this using PrimeFaces Mobile:

```
<body onload="windowOnLoad();">
```

This is what the page looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:pm="http://primefaces.org/mobile" contentType="text/html"
    renderKitId="PRIMEFACES_MOBILE">

    <pm:page title="Mobile Login">
    <pm:header>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function bodyOnLoad() {
    alert("in bodyOnLoad");
}

</script>
</pm:header>

        <pm:view id="viewForm">
            <pm:content onload="bodyOnLoad();">

Test

            </pm:content>
        </pm:view>
    </pm:page>
</f:view>
```

I've tried putting it on the pm:page, pm:view, pm:content.  None seem to work?  I am sure I am missing something easy.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned into more of a Javascript solution:

```
<pm:header>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function bodyOnLoad() {
    alert("in bodyOnLoad");
}
window.onload = bodyOnLoad;

</script>
</pm:header>
```